# Angular Material Design Input elements invisible on page load

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material-7

I'm practicing the use of Anuglar Material Design components. I have gone through the regular steps to add Angular Material using 'ng add @angular/material' and selected one of the themes and okayed other defaults.

Everything works well, except that the form inputs are not visible in any of the browsers. They become visible only after intuitively clicking on the screen, guessing where the input maybe present. When I focus out of the input, the input field disappears

```js
//app module ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input'
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatInputModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

//app component ts
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  
})


export class AppComponent {
  title = 'ang-mat-design';
}
```

```css
<!--no code added -->
```

```html
<mat-form-field appearance = "fill">
    <input matInput placeholder = "Input">
    <mat-hint>Sample Hint</mat-hint>
 </mat-form-field>
```

[image: only one mat input element is present but doesnt show up on page load. Sorry I couldn't grab the screen with focus on input field, which disappears after blur]

Comment: Could you please provide your app's module file, as well as a [mcve] of your code?

Comment: @Edric please view the changes. I have added the minimal code in a freshly created project.

Comment: Looks like you're missing the module used for the form-field itself - you can fix this issue by importing and declaring `MatFormFieldModule` from `@angular/material/form-field` in your app's module.

Comment: Getting following error:
Failed to compile.

node_modules/@angular/material/form-field/form-field.d.ts:64:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

This likely means that the library (@angular/material/form-field) which declares MatFormField has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

Comment: What version of Angular and Angular Material are you using? Could you try stopping `ng serve` and/or run the `ngcc` command from `node_modules/.bin/ngcc`?